# String to DateTime conversion in .NET compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I am using .NET compact Framework, more precisely using Windows mobile 6.0 and
was trying to convert a string to datetime but seems it is not supported.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim provider AS CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim dt AS DateTime = Convert.ToDatetime("5/2/2013 5:15:03 PM")
```

Getting a formatexception issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post the relevant code segment.

Comment: @Devlin please find the code below

Dim provider AS CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim dt AS DateTime = Convert.ToDatetime("5/2/2013 5:15:03 PM")
Getting a formatexception issue..

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following .NET Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IGvsrD).

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim provider AS CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US")
        Dim dt AS DateTime = Convert.ToDatetime("5/2/2013 5:15:03 PM") 
        Console.WriteLine(dt)
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d",provider))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output:

[image: output]